# My web page is fuzzy in Chrome and mozilla but not in Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

I have got a big problem...

I would like to host my c#.NET page somewhere and I found www.somee.com/default.aspx but I have got some issues.

I cant see correctly my web page in Chrome and Mozilla, but yes in Explorer. The web page is hosted here: http://pintxopote.somee.com/

The code of github: https://github.com/aaltzi/Pintxopote

I really apreciate if someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? I see your page with background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the styling your application is using, I found this statement in your business-casual.css file:

```
filter: blur(10px);
```

Commented it, and it ran fine on chrome. Internet Explorer simply wasn't recognising this CSS statement, that explains why the website's running fine there.

[image: Running fine on Chrome !!]

So, you just need to remove (or simply comment) that line from the .css file. That'll work.